# How to use Intent constructor

Tags: android, android-intent

Thi is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  Button bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAcitvity.class);
                EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
                String text=et.getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("name",text);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my SecondActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondAcitvity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        Bundle b=i.getExtras();
        if(b!=null)
        {
String name=(String)b.get("name");
            tv.setText(name);

        }

    }
}
```

Whe I am using

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAcitvity.class);
```

then code is running fine

but when I am using

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,SecondAcitvity.class);
```

then it is giving error.

Cannot resolve constructor

> Intent(anonymous android.view.View.onClickListener,java.lang.Class{com.example.intents.SecondActivity})`

Why so?

Comment: what error actually you are getting

Comment: Inside the `OnClickListener`, `this` refers to the `OnClickListener`, which is not a `Context`, which is what that `Intent` constructor expects.

Comment: because you are in the `View.OnClickListener` interface, so if you use `this`, it means that you call this interface, not the `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

The this keyword references the class that you are currently in.

```
Button bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i=new Intent(this, SecondAcitvity.class);
          EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
          String text = et.getText().toString();
          i.putExtra("name",text);
          startActivity(i);
     }
});
```

You would actually reference the `View.OnClickListener();` so what you are basically doing when writing the above code is saying this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(new View.OnClickListener(), SecondActivity.class);
```

This construct is called an inner class. When you are inside an inner class (like the onClickListener implementation), you need to specifically target the outer class when using the `this` keyword.

So by saying `MainActivity.this`, you are explicitly asking to target the outer class (which is MainActivity).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling intent constructor in anonymous class and this refers to current instance. And when you are passing 'MainActivity.this' that means you are explicitly saying what instance to consider. I hope answer the question.

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAcitvity.class);
            EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
            String text=et.getText().toString();
            i.putExtra("name",text);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bt.setOnClickListener it is actually creating an Anonymous Inner Class which implements OnClickListener. if you pass this in intent its reference of Anonymous Inner Class thats why you were getting error.you need to pass activity reference inside Intent.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,SecondAcitvity.class);
```